# I downloaded VueScan app and then uninstalled it, why is it appearing in my operating system update?

Tags: updates, applications, appcenter, flatpak

I was testing different apps/programs that could work with my printer/scanner. One of them was VueScan. It was the only app that worked but it isn't free so I uninstalled it. Why does it still appear on my updates? (photo below)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a `$ flatpak uninstall --unused` and got this response

```
        ID                                 Branch        Op
 1. [-] com.hamrick.VueScan.Locale         stable        r
 2. [-] org.gnome.Cheese.Locale            stable        r
 3. [-] org.gnome.Platform.Locale          3.34          r
 4. [-] org.kde.Platform                   5.14          r
 5. [-] org.kde.Platform.Locale            5.14          r
 6. [-] org.kde.kolourpaint.Locale         stable        r
 7. [-] org.mypaint.MyPaint.Locale         stable        r
```

pressed `y`

then `Uninstall complete.`

`AppCenter` is no longer asking for updates with VueScan.

Elementary OS dev team, please incorporate this in the AppCenter when uninstalling apps.

Reference: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/how-to-remove-unused-flatpak-runtimes.html